Datamining Unity based game with Frida/IdaPro
2 years ago i was able to pull config files in terms of datamining from Android unity based game.
I was using tools like il2cpp dumper, idaPro and Frida to make this.
After some time, i wanted to make it again with the same game after many updates, following the same steps but iam not able to read specific function offset with IdaPro anymore.
Ida instead of showing all functions that are in assemblycsharp is showing only couple of them related to ads etc.
Anyone here is able to help?

Unity uses AFAIK Xamarin/Mono or as it now called MAUI which uses .Net/Mono DLL files. How to get and decompile these files depends on the app and how the dlls files are stored. Sometimes they are simply include din the asset folder, sometimes all dll files are packed together or they are ahead-of-time compiled into aot files.
